# How to see commits that were merged in to a merge commit?

Tags: git, branch, git-merge, git-commit, git-log

If `my-feature-branch` was merged into `my-main-branch`, how can I see what commits were merged in from `my-feature-branch`?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you want to see every commits merged in the last merge you can try that :

```
git log $(git merge-base --octopus \
$(git log -1 --merges --pretty=format:%P)).. --boundary
```

Here is an example of my current log :

```
$ git log --graph --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
* 44899b9 pouf
*   8f49f9c Merge branch 'test'
|\  
| * 3db39ca test
* | 69f431c pif
* | df1f51c lala
|/  
* 8fae178 pif2
* 20f8ba6 init
```

If I only want commits related to the last merge I have to use `git log -1 --merges --pretty=format:%P` which gives me the parents of the first merge available :

```
$ git log -1 --merges --pretty=format:%P
69f431cec7859b61d33c7503c9431ceea2aaf3e0 3db39ca3ab1e8f70462db23d94590628b5e7ad7b
```

Now that I know which parents I need to track, I need their common base that I can obtain through `git merge-base --octopus` (--octopus is there just in case) :

```
$ git merge-base --octopus \
$(git log -1 --merges \
--pretty=format:%P)
8fae178666e34a480b22e40f858efd9e7c66c3ca
```

Now with `git log` I can search every commit since the base to the current `HEAD`:

```
$ git log $(git merge-base --octopus \
$(git log -1 --merges --pretty=format:%P)).. \
--boundary --graph --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit 
* 44899b9 pouf
*   8f49f9c Merge branch 'test'
|\  
| * 3db39ca test
* | 69f431c pif
* | df1f51c lala
|/  
o 8fae178 pif2
```

If you're a bit perfectionist you can also do this :

```
$ git log 
$(git merge-base --octopus \
$(git log -1 \
--merges --pretty=format:%P))..$(git log -1 --merges --pretty=format:%H) \
--boundary --graph --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit 
*   8f49f9c Merge branch 'test'
|\  
| * 3db39ca test
* | 69f431c pif
* | df1f51c lala
|/  
o 8fae178 pif2
```

Now I think I'll keep this as an alias :)

The `--graph --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit` options are optional.

---

**Resources :**

- [Git merge-base](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-base.html)
- [Git log](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)
- [Git revision](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html)

Comment: `git log --graph --oneline` is a shortcut for `git log --graph --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit`.

Comment: I made this answer more comfortable for daily use [in this repository](https://github.com/taljacob2/git-log-merge). You are welcome to use this.

Comment: This includes a lot more commits than the top voted answer. If I remove `--boundary` then I get the same number, but I don't know why as I don't fully understand all the pieces involved.

Answer (score 84):

`git log abc123^..abc123`
shows the commits that got merged into merge-commit `abc123`.

Create a `git` alias `log-merge` for easy reuse:

```
$ git config --global alias.log-merge \
'!f() { git log --stat "$1^..$1"; }; f'
$ git log-merge abc123
```

For a one-line version:

```
$ git config --global alias.log-merge-short \
'!f() { git log --pretty=oneline "$1^..$1"; }; f'
```

Comment: This solution is great.  I modified a version of the command so we could get a "short" version: 


    `$ git config --global alias.merge-log-short '!f() { git log --pretty=oneline "$1^..$1"; }; f'`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a merge commit (say `a2345`) and say `git log -1 a2345`, it will tell you the names of the parents (i.e. the commits which got merged in this commit). Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yep, that's what I wanted (only showing 1 commit though). I assume you can do this for the normal git log view too?

Comment: Yes. If you want to browse parents of a larger number of commits, the GUI (gitk) is more useful. The restriction to a single commit is because of the `-1`. Drop that and you'll get the regular log.

Comment: if I drop the `-1` it shows all the log of all commit messages, this seems not useful