# Git: list different commits, but keep reverts in mind

Tags: git

Is there a way to list commits from branch A that aren't in branch B, but if there are any commits that are in A and B, but reverted in B, show those as well?

Something similar to:

```
git log --oneline A ^B
```

So, let's say I have branch C that was merged into A, and then accidentally merged into B.  The merge was then reverted in B.  B still technically contains the commits from C, so the above command won't list the commits in C... but in my case, I want the command to also show such commits.

Answer (score 1):

If you used `git revert` to revert the commits, you should see in `git log A..B` the "merge" commit and the "revert merge" commit.

Then you will have to use the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191138/show-commits-in-a-git-merge) to show what commits were in this reverted merge.

In short :

`git log $(git merge-base --octopus $(git log -1 --pretty=format:%P THE_HASH_OF_THE_MERGE_COMMIT))..THE_HASH_OF_THE_MERGE_COMMIT`