# How can I show git commits related to a task and their merge information?

Tags: git, version-control, github

Part of the *fun* of this question is *defining what a task is* and how it is recorded in git history.

When you use the [git flow branching model](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) each developed feature gets its own branch. Then, using the following script which I got from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6191836/172690:

```
#!/bin/sh
# From https://stackoverflow.com/a/6191836/172690

NAME1="$1"
if [[ -z $NAME1 ]]; then
    echo "Usage:
    git-show-merge-ancestry.sh COMMIT_ID
        This will display the ancestry of the merged in branch.
        To list only merge commits, use 'git log --merges'."
else
    git show $1 | grep Merge: > /dev/null
    if [[ 0 == $? ]]; then
        echo "Displaying ancestry of merged commit $1"
        git show $1
        git log $(git merge-base --octopus $(git log -1 --merges --pretty=format:%P ${NAME1}))..$(git log -1 --merges --pretty=format:%H ${NAME1}) --boundary --graph --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
    else
        echo "The commit $1 doesn't seem to be a merge commit"
    fi
fi
```

I can easily look at a merge commit and extract all the juicy information of commits related to the merged branch/feature. However, *shit happens* and sometimes the commits really related to a single task/feature are actually scattered through more than a single branch. In fact, that's what sometimes I use hotfixes for, patching a feature.

In these situations I *back up* by adding to each commit a **Refs #xxx** marker. These kind of marker shows up in github and similar ticketing systems, and is my definitive manual way of tracking changes related to a task. Then the changes related to the task can be extracted with a command like `git log --grep=#39` which greps the log commits for a specific number.

The question is: how can I mix both informations into a single view? What I would like is a command which would accept either a **Refs #xxx** marker or a commit hash and show all the related information, no matter how scattered through the git history. If the input is the task, it should first grep individual commits, then find out which branches they came from. If the input is a commit hash, it should parse its ancestry logs for **Refs #xxx** markers and find out what other commits in the history reference those tasks.

Since this is a more complex feature maybe it is implemented in any of the git graphical browsers?