# How to get all the commits for a merge request in git?

Tags: git

The `git show --raw` command will show if a commit hash was generated from a merge:

```
$ git show --raw -m 3d1718
commit 3d1718fb99d52d35700b596bac45caffd1af00dc (from 8923654049aa49c4813fa612e4108271e0361240)
Merge: 8923654 3f1a071
...
```

In the case where the merge came from a fork into origin/master, parsing the output will reveal which commit hash was the HEAD of origin/master and which commit hash came from the fork. So far, so good.

Once I have the commit hash from the fork, how would I generate a list of hashes for all the commits that are part of that merge? The history might look like this:

```
H---->J---->W    origin/master
 \         /
  Q-->R-->T      fork
```

In this case, the `git show --raw -m` command would be executed on the hash for W, and I can get the hash for T. But how do I get the hashes for Q and R?

Comment: Side note (not relevant to your question but it explains a lot about Git :-) ): the internal arrows that Git maintains all point *backwards*, from W to J and T, for instance, and from T to R, and so on. Git works backwards. Any time you find yourself wondering: *why did Git do **that**?*, remember: *oh yeah... Git works backwards* :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this as duplicate of [How to see commits that were merged in to a merge commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191138/how-to-see-commits-that-were-merged-in-to-a-merge-commit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would:

```
git log master~..fork --oneline
```

Suit you?

It logs all the commits in `fork` but not in `master~` (one commit before the merge).

In term of commits, it would be:

```
git log J..T --oneline
```

Answer (score -1):

`git log $(git merge-base --octopus $(git log -1 --merges --pretty=format:%P)).. --boundary`
[Show commits involved in a prior git merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191138/show-commits-involved-in-a-prior-git-merge)