# How to find out which commits are included in one merge commit?

Tags: git

For example, I have a merge commit

```
commit MERGE-COMMIT-ID
Merge: commit1 commit2
```

I would like to know what commits are included in this merge.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the parents of a merge commit in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059335/how-to-get-the-parents-of-a-merge-commit-in-git)

Comment: @JoeW AFAIU the OP asks how to list commits in the merged branches since the merge base.

Comment: @phd Your crystal ball is better than mine, clearly :-) I was about to ask about it but you're probably right.

Comment: @phd makes sense. In that case it would be this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191138/show-commits-involved-in-a-prior-git-merge

Answer (score 0):

yo can use `git log <hash>` for example

`git log f5c6e83496a373c4ebb3adf89e79c8c6ce057adb
commit f5c6e83496a373c4ebb3adf89e79c8c6ce057adb (origin/development, origin/HEAD, development)
Merge: b445d90 0ac84a2
Author: author
Date:   Thu Oct 10 22:08:36 2019 -0400
    Merge pull request #94 from author/feature/13-jobs-crud        Fixed stuff
commit 0ac84a239b438cea909422fcc88b0cb6a4ccdb9d
Author: author
Date:   Thu Oct 10 22:06:26 2019 -0400
    Fixed stuff
commit b445d90579690199680775b2475e5e4a795af8cdMerge: b0736d1 0eb371a
Author: author
Date:   Thu Oct 10 21:57:48 2019 -0400
    Merge pull request #93 from author/feature/13-jobs-crud    :`