# Azure Pipelines find commit hash of incoming merge

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm relatively new to git and am having the below problem

I have a pipeline, and I'm trying to find the commit hash of the incoming pull request / merge, store it,  and use it elsewhere in a simple git log command.

So is there a git command (or powershell script) that can find the incoming merge commit hash of a PR?

Sorry in advance if the answer is obvious my google fu did not help with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) should work. If you just pass in the PR number you will receive a JSON response of type [GitPullRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#gitpullrequest):

```
_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullrequests/{pullRequestId}
```

`{pullRequestId}` might be 1234, for example.

Included in the JSON response are different commit IDs, including *lastMergeCommit*, *lastMergeSourceCommit*, and *lastMergeTargetCommit*. Take a look at those IDs to confirm which one you want. You can also access an array of *commits* contained in the PR.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see every commits merged in the last merge you can try that :

```
git log $(git merge-base --octopus $(git log -1 --merges --pretty=format:%P)).. --boundary
```

Check this case for more details: [Show commits involved in a prior git merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191138/show-commits-involved-in-a-prior-git-merge)